# Why sorting posts doesn't work properly?

Tags: posts, wp-query

I tried a lot of methods to sort posts while getting via query but it always fails if I use `DESC`:

[image]

My code:

```
   <?php 
        // the query

        $args = array(               
            'orderby' => array(
                'post_date' => 'DESC',
            )
        );

        // The Query
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        
        // The Loop
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            echo '<ul>';
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                $the_query->the_post();
                echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '<br>' . get_the_date().'</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        } else {
            // no posts found
        }
        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();
        
   ?>
```

Also if I order them by ASC, the order will be correct, however `DESC` doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `post_date` is not listed in the official documentation as a valid value for orderby, that's not how that parameter works https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by `'ignore_sticky_posts' => true`